# How can I selectively escape percent (%) in Python strings?

Tags: python, escaping, python-2.7

I have the following code

```
test = "have it break."
selectiveEscape = "Print percent % in sentence and not %s" % test

print(selectiveEscape)
```

I would like to get the output:

```
Print percent % in sentence and not have it break.
```

What actually happens:

```
    selectiveEscape = "Use percent % in sentence and not %s" % test
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str
```

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: But I have personally met the problem when the formatting template was read from a file.  If you have no control over what is inside the file, then the question is legitimate.

Comment: If the formatting template is in a file, then getting the template correct - including proper escaping of `%` symbols - is the responsibility of the file creator.

Comment: Why isn't it `\%`? That was my guess, I'm surprised to find it's `%%` instead - seems pretty counterintuitive.

Comment: `% i` means "a decimal representation of an integer, padded left with spaces.

Comment: The escape is to the function, not the language syntax.  Hence if the escape was `\%` it would actually be `\\%` when written in ordinary code.  `<escape><escape>` is the typical pattern I've seen, and ``\`` happens to be the most common escape character, for better or worse.

Comment: @Demis and how do you escape `\ ` if you had to print `\\%`? You are bound to require escaping through repetition of special characters, if the special characters are also not special depending on circumstances.

Comment: I think it is annoying in Python that the the literal % is encoded by "%%" and not by "\%".

Comment: @Ralf I find it more confusing that when I need to escape `%` in LaTeX mode, `r'\%'` doesn't work but `r'\%%'` works

Answer (score 737, accepted):

```
>>> test = "have it break."
>>> selectiveEscape = "Print percent %% in sentence and not %s" % test
>>> print selectiveEscape
Print percent % in sentence and not have it break.
```

Comment: In Python 3.3.5, `print('%s%%' % 100)` prints `100%`. But `print('%%')` prints `%%`. So it looks like you don't have to escape the % signs if you don't make substitutions.

Comment: @Zenadix This is true in Python 2.7 as well

Comment: Note that the `%` method is actually deprecated (in Python 3) in favor of `str.format()`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format

Comment: Note that the `%` method is not depreciated in Python 3.6. It will continue to be supported in lieu of its similarity to c, c++, etc. `str.format()` and f-strings are preferred but not enforced.

Comment: Just noticed that If the string is a json string, being read from a file you don't even need to escape the `%` sign. Just `%` will do

Comment: You can also be sneaky and do `print "Print percent %" + "variable %s" % 'text'` as a dirty workaround.

Comment: @Zenadix that is because it is **not string escaping**, but a *completely different* escape mechanism that is processed *by the `%` operator* (at the same time that it's scanning for `%s` symbols). So it's the same reason that `print('%s')` prints `%s` and doesn't give any kind of error. A similar thing happens with regexes, but it's much more confusing there because regex syntax also uses the ``\`` character for escaping and because people use "raw strings" with an `r` prefix to cut down on the backslashes, then mistakenly think the `r` means "regex".

Answer (score 62):

Alternatively, as of Python 2.6, you can use new string formatting (described in [PEP 3101](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/)):

```
'Print percent % in sentence and not {0}'.format(test)
```

which is especially handy as your strings get more complicated.

Comment: The only problem with this is when the text you want to format is HTML with a CSS style section.

Comment: What do you recommend for text formatting HTML that contains a CSS style section, @Broseph?

Comment: I was wrong. If you use double braces in your CSS you are fine.

Comment: Edit queues are full, but the http URL in this answer's link now redirects to an https URL (https://peps.python.org/pep-3101/). Could someone edit the new URL in when the queues are less full?

Answer (score 49):

try using `%%` to print % sign .

Answer (score 10):

You can't selectively escape `%`, as `%` always has a special meaning depending on the following character.

In the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) of Python, at the bottem of the second table in that section, it states:

```
'%'        No argument is converted, results in a '%' character in the result.
```

Therefore you should use:

```
selectiveEscape = "Print percent %% in sentence and not %s" % (test, )
```

(please note the expicit change to tuple as argument to `%`)

Without knowing about the above, I would have done:

```
selectiveEscape = "Print percent %s in sentence and not %s" % ('%', test)
```

with the knowledge you obviously already had.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using **Python 3.6** or newer, you can use [f-string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/):

```
>>> test = "have it break."
>>> selectiveEscape = f"Print percent % in sentence and not {test}"
>>> print(selectiveEscape)
... Print percent % in sentence and not have it break.
```

Comment: Would be nice to see how to escape { here

Comment: You just make it double `{{`

Answer (score 3):

If the formatting template was read from a file, and you cannot ensure the content doubles the percent sign, then you probably have to detect the percent character and decide programmatically whether it is the start of a placeholder or not.  Then the parser should also recognize sequences like `%d` (and other letters that can be used), but also `%(xxx)s` etc.

Similar problem can be observed with the new formats -- the text can contain curly braces.