# Python testing whether a string has "%" and not have it break

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've look at this answer: [How can I selectively escape percent (%) in Python strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678229/selectively-escape-percent-in-python) and I believe my problem is different.

I'm trying to convert a percentage to decimal, but first I need to test if a percentage signs exists. My data is in a `dataframe`. My code is:

`df[i]=df[i].map(lambda x: float(x.strip('%'))/100 if '%' in x)`

This gives me `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Why do you need to check if the `%` exists?  `strip` will still work if there is no `%`, it just won't do anything if there's nothing to strip.

Comment: @brenbarn. I have other data that is not a percentage, so if i don't test, it will divide everything by `100`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need `else` in `lambda` like this

```
lambda x: float(x.strip('%'))/100 if '%' in x else x
```

Comment: I think that worked. So it was not a `%` break after all? why do I need the `else x`? `lambda` must do something?

Comment: It is syntax problem. There is no `result_if_true if condition`, there is only `result_if_true if condition else result_if_false`