# Python: how to escape "%s"

Tags: python, string, formatting

I'm trying to make a string that includes a "%s" with no formatting

For example, I want this:

```
#I want to make mystring = "x %s"

first_value = "x"
mystring = "%s %s" % first_value
```

So, I want to format the first %s, but leave the second %s in the string.. Of course the above code gives me a "TypeError:not enough arguments for format string"

Is there a way to achieve this in one line?

Thanks

**EDIT:**
I know I can do

```
mystring = "%s %s" % (first_value, "%s")
```

but this kind of looks ugly.. Is there a better way?

Comment: Use `%%s` `>>> x = 'asdad'
>>> mystring = "%%s %s" % x
>>> mystring
'%s asdad'
`

Comment: possible duplicate of [selectively escape percent (%) in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678229/selectively-escape-percent-in-python)

Answer (score 13):

You can escape a `%` character in a format string by doubling it:

```
>>> "%s %%s" % "x"
"x %s"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can assign your string like this:

```
mystring = "{} %s".format(first_value)
```

If you are working with Python 2.6 or earlier, you will need to add an integer index in the curly braces:

```
mystring = "{0} %s".format(first_value)
```

A nice thing about this method is that `first_value` can change types later and you don't have to adjust your definition of `mystring` because `.format()` can take different types, and you don't need `first_value`'s type to match a format string.

I also think it looks cleaner than escaping percent signs, but I know that is very subjective.

Comment: You can drop the integer index in python2.7 as well.  AFAIK, python2.6 is the only version that supports `.format` where the index is required for positional arguments.

Comment: @mgilson Wow. You are exactly right. My world just got turned upside down. I have been typing unnecessary characters in 2.7 for FAR TOO LONG to not be ashamed of it.

Comment: FWIW, I like the extra numbers in there.  I find that it's more explicit and I like my code to be as backward compatible as possible if it's not terribly inconvenient. . . But I'm sure that others would probably consider that a pointless exercise . . .

Comment: @mgilson I just hate it when I change the arguments being inserted into the string and then have to go back and shift all the indexes by one. I would much rather dump all the numbers so I only have to change the arguments to `.format()` and add another set of curly brackets.

Comment: Fair enough -- Although if you have that many, it's probably time to start naming them :-)  `'{name} ...'.format(name='Bam Bam', strength='unbelievable')`

Answer (score 1):

Prepend `%s` with a `%` to escape it:

```
mystring = "%s %%s" % first_value
'x %s'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try concatenating instead:

```
mystring = ("%s " % first_value) + "%s"
```

outputs `x %s`

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the first '%' by leading it with a second:

```
 print "%%s%s" % 'hello world'
```

> %shello world