# How to pass a value into sql "LIKE" query

Tags: sql, python-3.x

i need to input a value into sql query, here is my code:

```
"UPDATE xxx SET status = (%s) WHERE author LIKE (%s)", ("OK", phone))
```

author value should start with value that i pass in 'phone' var

how should i write sql query in this case?

Comment: this seems relevent https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26393895/python-how-to-escape-s

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to safely generate a SQL LIKE statement using python db-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097475/how-to-safely-generate-a-sql-like-statement-using-python-db-api)

Answer (score 1):

Append `'%'` to your variable.

```
phone = phone + '%'
```