# How do I add a % symbol to my Python script

Tags: python

Here is my code. I need to add a percent symbol at the end of the `print` string. I can't get this figured out.

```
total = 0
counter = 0
while True:
    score = int(input('Enter test score: '))
    if score == 0:
        break
    total += score
    counter += 1
average = total / counter
print('The average is:', format(average, ',.3f'))
```

Comment: What does `format` do?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678229/how-can-i-selectively-escape-percent-in-python-strings

Comment: @PeterWood It’s a [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format).

Comment: @PierreLafortune No, this question doesn’t use percent-formatting.

Comment: I agree. There may be a dupe though. The upvoted answer here is only workaround. It doesn't answer the direct question of escaping the percent operator.

Comment: @PierreLafortune I think you are overinterpreting this question; there was never a need to escape the percent *symbol*. The second argument to `format` is only for the format specification, characters that should be displayed in the output would never belong there, so you wouldn’t have to escape anything. The unfortunately downvoted answer perfectly explains how to add a percent character at the end of the printed string, as OP is asking for.

Comment: @poke tough crowd maybe. I upvoted the answer, maybe it can get more attention.

Comment: @poke I have never noticed that before! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
print('The average is: ' + format(average, ',.3f') + '%')
```

?

Comment: This *literally* answers the question (albeit not showing the best way to solve the problem), so I’m giving it an upvote.

Comment: plus one for answering the question directly.

Answer (score 6):

The probably best way would be to just use the percent format type:

```
format(average, '.1%')

# or using string formatting:
'{:.1%}'.format(average)
```

This already multiplies the `average` by 100 and will also show a percent sign at the end.

```
>>> average = .123
>>> print('The average is: {:.1%}'.format(average))
The average is: 12.3%
```