# Python "ValueError: incomplete format" upon print("stuff %" % "thingy")

Tags: python, string, format

My goal with this code is that when you put in a certain number, you will get printed the number and some other output, based on what you typed. For some reason, what I have here gives the error "ValueError: incomplete format". It has something to do with the %. What does the error mean, and how do I fix it? Thanks!

```
variable = "Blah"
variable2 = "Blahblah"

text = raw_input("Type some stuff: ")

if "1" in text:
    print ("One %" % variable)
elif "2" in text:
    print ("Two %" % variable2)
```

Comment: `"One %s" % variable` (Note _%s_)

Comment: '%s %%' % variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I selectively escape percent (%) in Python strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678229/how-can-i-selectively-escape-percent-in-python-strings)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Python is expecting another character to follow the `%` in the string literal to tell it how to represent `variable` in the resulting string.

Instead use

```py
"One %s" % (variable,)
```

or

```py
"One {}".format(variable)
```

to create a new string where the string representation of `variable` is used instead of the placeholder.

Comment: Here is the [Python documentation on this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting) and also a [very nice tutorial](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_formatted_output.php). The tutorial also describes the newer, [``format()`` style of formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax), but the older ``%`` style is still much used because, although less powerful, it is often more convenient.

Answer (score 13):

```
>>> variable = "Blah"
>>> '%s %%' % variable
    'Blah %'
>>>
```

Comment: Curious,  what version of python did you use for this to work, 3x or 2x?  (I am using 2.7.13, where it does not seem to work)

Comment: @ryyker, I just tested with Python 3.5.2 - works fine. As far as I can tell it *should* also work for 2.7, according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678229/how-can-i-selectively-escape-percent-in-python-strings).

Comment: this doesn't really answer the question but actually solves the problem I had when stumbling upon this question

Answer (score 1):

an easy way:

```
print ("One " + variable)
```

Comment: Or just `print("One", variable)` which works for both strings and non strings, but only in Python 3.x