# Parsing the commands to another software interface using python

Tags: python, linux, parsing, interface, cmd

I am using python to generate command list for another software interface.
Using command

```
sensorik.cmd('list curve')
```

will put the text

```
list curve
```

in that interface and it lists all curves in that program up to that point. Now I have to introduce a loop of commands, here is a sample

```
sideset 1  curve 1
sideset 2  curve 2
sideset 3  curve 3
```

I used

```
for curveID in range (1, 4):
print "sideset %d  curve %d" % (curveID, curveID)
sensorik.cmd('print "sideset %d  curve %d" % (curveID, curveID)')
sensorik.cmd('sideset %d  curve %d" % (curveID, curveID)')
```

This however, doesnot work and the interface gets the command

```
print "sideset %d  curve %d" % (curveID, curveID)
```

and it does print the required text on the shell prompt but does not parse it to the software when used in sensorik.cmd. Instead the software gets

```
print "sideset %d  curve %d" % (curveID, curveID)
print "sideset %d  curve %d" % (curveID, curveID)
print "sideset %d  curve %d" % (curveID, curveID)
```

any suggestions?

Comment: What about `sensorik.cmd('print "sideset %d  curve %d"' % (curveID, curveID))`?

Comment: @PeterWood, it is giving an error. ERROR: <stdin>, line 77
       Unrecognized Keyword: 'print'

Comment: Should the other software understand `print`?

Comment: It should not understand.. it should only get the result generated by our commands.. like   print "sideset %d  curve %d" % (curveID, curveID)  prints the text as sideset 1 curve 1 from curveID=1.. the software should only get this text of     sideset 1 curve 1.

Comment: `%` interpolates strings, `print` prints the interpolated string. You don't need `print`.

Comment: You suggest like sensorik.cmd('sideset %d curve %d' % (curveID, curveID)) ? or

Comment: Yes, no need for `print`

Comment: Well, I think the question would need improving before I'd answer it. I'm not sure how someone would have the same problem and find this question. The tags aren't relevant other than [tag:python], the problem was a misunderstanding of what role `print` (doesn't) play in creating interpolated strings.

Comment: ok, I would find a suitable edit so that the question is more general. Thanks for your valuable input, for me it is more clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not:

```
cmd = 'print "sideset %d  curve %d" %% (curveID, curveID)' % (curveID, curveID)
sensorik.cmd( cmd )
```

You need `%%` to escape percent symbol as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678229/how-can-i-selectively-escape-percent-in-python-strings) pointed out.

Comment: it is giving the error: ERROR: <stdin>, line 77 Unrecognized Keyword: 'print'

Comment: @HamadHassan It's not the question (you asked) about constructing the command. You make what you need. ex. use `echo` for bash instead of `print`. Or just remove if it shouldn't be used.