# Why does format() break this Python string?

Tags: python

**I can't figure out why the following string is broken:**

```
print '{% extends \"{base_route_name}.html\" %}'.format(base_route_name='base')
```

**It returns the following error:**

```
KeyError: '% extends "{base_route_name}'
```

I've tried using double `%%` as suggested in answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678229/how-can-i-selectively-escape-percent-in-python-strings) and other escaping measures to no avail.

**The only way I was able to fix it was to do this:**

```
print '{% extends \"' + base_route_name + '.html\" %}'
```

Any ideas why using `format()` wasn't working?

Comment: Because  the `{` and `}` characters are the metacharacters in `str.format()`, not `%`.

Comment: You also don't need to escape `"` characters if you're using `'` for strings.

Comment: It looks like you're creating a string for a templating engine... if so, you should be using that to handle placeholders...

Comment: I'm actually creating pages dynamically outside of the web app and this particular placeholder is generated using specific parameters.