# How to print % in python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to print output like that:
    Percentual de sapos: 25.00 %
I write this following code:

```
print("Percentual de sapos: %i.2f %"%Z)
```

But it didn't work. 
How to print "%" in output by python..?

Comment: Duplicate of [How can I selectively escape percent (%) in Python strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678229/how-can-i-selectively-escape-percent-in-python-strings).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I selectively escape percent (%) in Python strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678229/how-can-i-selectively-escape-percent-in-python-strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print("Percentual de sapos: {:.2f} %".format(Z))`

This question is duplicated:[How can I selectively escape...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678229/how-can-i-selectively-escape-percent-in-python-strings)