# Saving lists in python as semicolon delimited text file

Tags: python, python-2.7, save

I have three lists in Python. I want to save these lists as a semicolon delimited text file (with a heading).

For example, lets consider these three lists:

```
l1 = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5']
l2 = [1,2,3,4,5]
l3 = [20.0, 25.1, 51.2, 60.2, 75.0]
```

and header, `['Label1', 'Label2', 'Label3']`

I want these lists to be saved as columns in a text file in the following form:

```
Label1; Label2; Label3
a1;1;20.0%
a2;2;25.1%
a3;3;51.2%
a4;4;60.2%
a5;5;75.0%
```

In addition to saving the file in the above format, I want to have percentage symbols while writing the last column. I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678229/how-can-i-selectively-escape-percent-in-python-strings) post, but I am still confused about how I can implement this. I am using python 2.7.

I will really appreciate any help.

Comment: Wouldn't it be much more useful to save 0.2 instead of 20%?

Comment: timgeb: Thanks for your suggestion. I would have liked to follow your suggestion. But, I need to adhere to a laid standard here.

Comment: Why are there extra spaces in the header line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following will work, using the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
l1 = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5']
l2 = [1,2,3,4,5]
l3 = [20.0, 25.1, 51.2, 60.2, 75.0]
header = ['Label1', 'Label2', 'Label3'] 

import csv

with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';')
    w.writerow(header)
    for row in zip(l1, l2, (str(x)+'%' for x in l3)):
        w.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
l1 = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5']
l2 = [1,2,3,4,5]
l3 = [20.0, 25.1, 51.2, 60.2, 75.0]
answer = ''
for i in range(len(l1)):
    value = "{0};{1};{2}%".format(l1[i], l2[i], l3[i])
    answer = answer+"\n"+value

header = ['Label1', 'Label2', 'Label3'] 
title = ';'.join(header)
answer = title + answer
print(answer)

file = open("answer.txt","w") 
file.write(answer)
file.close()
```

Comment: in place of the print write to the file

Comment: Alfred Ayi-bonte: Thanks for your answer. How can I save this string 'answer' as a text file? Also, I would like to keep the header as the first row in my text file. How can I do this?

Comment: @Ross use
```
file = open("answer.txt","w") 
file.write(answer)
file.close()``` to write your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can transpose your rows using `zip` and then process them with the `csv` module.

```
>>> import csv
>>> l1 = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5']
>>> l2 = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> l3 = [20.0, 25.1, 51.2, 60.2, 75.0]
>>> l3_percent = ['{!r}%'.format(x) for x in l3]
>>> header = ['Label1', 'Label2', 'Label3']
>>> rows = zip(l1, l2, l3_percent)
>>>
>>> with open('out.csv', 'w') as f:
...:    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
...:    writer.writerow(header)
...:    writer.writerows(rows)
```

This produces

> Label1;Label2;Label3
>   a1;1;20.0%
>   a2;2;25.1%
>   a3;3;51.2%
>   a4;4;60.2%
>   a5;5;75.0%

Comment: timgeb: Thanks very much. Your suggestion works perfectly well. :-)