# Percent signs in windows path

Tags: python

I want to do this path ('C:\\Users\\%username%\\AppData') but the percent signs used to determine who the user is, is messing up the whole path. I know that you use double backslashes but what do I do when it comes to percent signs?

Thank you, sincerely a python noob :)

Comment: check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678229/how-can-i-selectively-escape-percent-in-python-strings) about how to escape %

Comment: @KevinFang But I do not wish to print % I just need it in my path to define the username of the computer. The percent messes with the backslashes in front of it.

Answer (score 3):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.path.html?highlight=expand#os.path.expandvars), I think you want to use the `os.path.expandvars` routine.

> On Windows, %name% expansions are supported in addition to $name and ${name}.

```
import os
my_path = "C:\\Users\\%username%\\AppData"
expanded_path = os.path.expandvars(my_path)
print("The expanded path is: {}".format(expanded_path))
```

This example works for me in the Python 3.6 command prompt in Windows 7.

Comment: Here maybe I can explain better with some screenshots 
[link](https://imgur.com/6ZYAEBJ) here is a screenshot, as you can see the percent sign and u are purple which they should not be. Thank you for your patience. Here is the whole code, 
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['C:\\Users\\%username%\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Accessories\\notepad.exe'])

Comment: I'm guessing the strange colors you're seeing are (to some degree) an edge case in the syntax highlighting in your code editor. What code editor are you using? I wouldn't worry too much about the colors at the moment. The pertinent question is does the code run and do what you expect?

Comment: @JonahBishop I am using sublime text 3, however it does not work. I don't know maybe \\% has some special meaning, like you cannot type C:\Users, you have to (in my case at least) type C:\\Users, the double backslash, I don't know if percent has a similar function.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include a print statement. Copy this code, place it in a script, and run it. The script should print out the appropriate path.

Comment: @JonahBishop Hi, I think I have identified the problem. Python identifies the %u part in %username% as a sort of command or something.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with your assessment, given that the snippet of code I have above runs without problems in Windows 7 on Python 3.6...

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try using `os.system`:

e.g.

```
import os
os.system('PATH')
```