# "unsupported format character at index "

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm trying to format a PostgreSQL query in python and that query has to have '%' between the name of a survey so I can filter surveys by name.

Here is the code:

```
sql = """select survey_data
from survey_data.survey_data 
where codigo_do_projeto like '%s%'
ORDER BY data_de_inicio_da_coleta desc 
limit %s
offset %s"""
```

However it throws this error:

> "unsupported format character 'P' (0x50) at index 79"

I don't know how to make python ignore the "%" character.

Comment: Can't you use a parametrized query instead? Injecting string directly like this potentially expose you for SQL Injection problems.

Comment: Use two percent signs (%%) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678229/how-can-i-selectively-escape-percent-in-python-strings

Comment: That's true! There is that problem I completely overlooked, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Two percent signs did not solve my problem.

Comment: I was using parametrized search but it wasn't working, so I gave format a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to escape the `%`.

```
sql = """select survey_data
from survey_data.survey_data 
where codigo_do_projeto like '%%'||%s||'%%'
ORDER BY data_de_inicio_da_coleta desc 
limit %s
offset %s"""
```

Or you can do:

```
search_val = '%search_term%'


sql = """select survey_data
from survey_data.survey_data 
where codigo_do_projeto like %s
ORDER BY data_de_inicio_da_coleta desc 
limit %s
offset %s"""

cur.execute(sql, [search_val, val2, val3])
```

Comment: Nice, it worked!
Thanks Adrian!

Answer (score -1):

You need to put the `survey_name` part inside single quotes:

```
sql = """SELECT survey_data
FROM survey_data.survey_data 
WHERE project_code like '%{0}%'
ORDER BY starting_date desc 
LIMIT {1} 
OFFSET {2}*{1}""".format(survey_name,items_per_page,page_number)
```

Comment: Same problem unfortunately.
SQL would complain about that, but it seems it is a Python error.

Comment: **Do not use** string interpolation for passing in parameters. See [Parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) for why and how to do this safetly.

Comment: Changed the code, I still have the same error

Comment: See my answer for solution.